# How to create a conditional transaction in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, postgres-10

I am trying to add new roles and modify existing ones inside a transaction like below:

```
BEGIN;

-- readonly role
CREATE ROLE readonly;
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM readonly;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE some_database FROM readonly;

...
...
...

COMMIT;
```

However I want to run this transaction only if `readonly` role doesn't exist. How can I put this transaction inside an `if condition` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a `plpgsql` function, which will automatically run within a transaction. The following does roughly what you have in your sample above I think:

```sql
DO $$
  DECLARE
    role_count int;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO role_count FROM information_schema.enabled_roles
    WHERE role_name = 'readonly';
  IF role_count = 0 THEN
    CREATE ROLE readonly;
    REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM readonly;
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE some_database FROM readonly;
    ...
    ...
    ...
  ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'readonly role already exists';
  END IF;
END$$;
```

As for the transaction semantics ... whilst you've tagged the question as pg 10, we've since confirmed you are running 11 so you have some options here.

- Run the above in isolation and it will run atomically, either all succeeding, or not altering the db
- You can wrap the above in a `BEGIN ... COMMIT/ROLLBACK` and have it run atomically with any surrounding logic you have in context.
- You also have the option of more granualr transactions if you convert to using procedures as per [plpgsql transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-transactions.html). Given your question, I don't think this will be necessary for you at this time.

HTH

Comment: You have a reputation of over 1500, so my understanding is that you should be able to add the tag. I have a mere 700 so am a long way off such glory days.